# Firebase Multiple Projects & Analytics Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a project on Firebase in this project i have multiple apps inside it e.g different flavors of the app. My question is is there a way to programmatically initailise these apps at runtime i have tried the following from the google firebase docs

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("project-name")
                .setApplicationId("mobilesdk_app_id")
                .setApiKey("ApiKey")
                .build();
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
```

The above is been called in the application level of the project but i get the error Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found
i get this error even if i add  `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "secondary");`

can anyone help out with this issue. Can multiple projects be used like this of do i have a different understanding of Firebase multiple projects can they even be used analytics tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the Firebase Analytics SDK can only log events to a single app at a time, which is the default app.  Calling initializeApp for other apps in the project won't change the way this works.

The only way that multiple apps are supported are for Firebase products that are not tied to the collection of Analytics.  And even then, it only makes sense for apps defined in multiple projects, not the same project.

Comment: Ah right ok so firebase products like database, remote testing etc Cheers

Comment: Does this apply to crashlytics? I'd like to aggregate multiple apps' crash data into one crashlytics dashboard